# Help verifying my proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I needed to prove by contradiction that a countable set is convergent to its accumulation points.

Comment: A suggestion for future posts: learn how to use MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to improve readability.

Comment: Thank you I will do so. I am not familiar with this website at all

Comment: Why is C  a subset of Q×Q?  Your use of C is too sloppy,  needs clarifying.

Comment: $\bigcup_x = \bigcup_y$ is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it: Let $I$ be the set of bounded open intervals with rational endpoints and let $J=\{i\in I: |S\cap i|\leq \aleph_0\}.$ Let $K=\bigcup J.$

Then $S\cap K=\cup_{j\in J}(S\cap j)$ is a countable union of countable sets, so $S\cap K$ is countable. So $S^*=S\setminus K=S\setminus (S\cap K)$ is an uncountable subset of $S.$

For any $x\in S^*$ and any $r>0,$ take $q,q'\in \Bbb Q$ with $-r+x<q<x<q'<r+x.$ Now if $S\cap (-r+x,r+x)$ were countable, then $S\cap (q,q')$ would be countable, implying $x\in (q,q')\in J,$ implying $x\in K,$ contrary to $x\in S^*=S\setminus K.$

So $S^*$ is an uncountable set such that every nbhd of every member of $S^*$ has uncountable intersection with $S.$

Furthermore, if $x\in S^*$ and $U$ is a nbhd of $x$ then $(S^*\cap U)\cup ((S\cap K)\cap U)=S\cap U$ is uncountable but $(S\cap K)\cap U$ is a subset of the countable set $S\cap K,$ so $S^*\cap U$ must be uncountable.

Comment: The core of the proof is that  (1) $I$ is countable so $J$ is countable so $S\cap K$ is countable, and (2) $ I $ is a base (basis) for the topology on $\Bbb R,$ so if $x\in \Bbb R$ and $r>0$  then there exists $i\in I $ such that $x\in i\subset (-r+x,r+x).$

Comment: What does J stand for

Comment: 1st paragraph: $J$ is the set of members of $I$ that have  countable intersection with $S$.